# How do I change the background to one and the same color during the whole boot process?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have just installed Xubuntu 20.04 (dual boot) and changed the purple background screen to green. Before I see the green login screen I see the "old" purple background for 0.5 second. Why is that? Can it be cured without loosing speed? In the past I tried to read a few old Linux books to understand more about grub, kernels etc., but I didn't understand a lot of it. Maybe you can give me the correct name of the process before the green screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu uses LDM not GDM. So gnome-extensions will be no help. They simply don't work with Xubuntu.

Go to the menu and select the "LightDM GTK+ Greeter Settings"
The following dialog opens:
[image]

Select "color" and choose the one you'd like

If you want to change the background color of you **desktop** - that is the color AFTER you've logged in - open the context menu on your desktop and select "Desktop Settings...". A dialog opens where you select "Style: None" and the background color you want:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Aha, that is why I had to change a Lightdm-file for the numlock key to be on in the login screen. But.. now I are having the right color for 0.5 second and then it changes to the regular background settings (GDM?). So I am having 2 colors of green after one another now. Am I using the Grome display manager instead of LightDM? I have performed the standard Xubuntu installation. The solution is to use the switch on the right top op the login screen? Thank you!

Comment: No, Standard is LightDM, it has nothing to do with GDM which is not installed. But you can select the "multihead setup" link. Have you tried that?

Comment: I see where it is, but I am afraid as it looks like that is something for multiple monitors and I only have one. Isn't it? The strangest thing happened when I changed the background color in the LightDM screen: When I wanted to shutdown my pc he fall asleep in the shutdown screen so I had to turn of the pc by long pressing the on-button. But.. now I still have the xubuntu-wallpaper.png on my desktop although I gave selected Color -> green. I only see the green for 0,5 second before I login.

Comment: Your description is not quit clear. You have the wallpaper AFTER you log in or BEFORE? 
Use the **edit** button below your question and add the information (not here in the comments) -And yes, if you have only one monitor, ignore my last answer

Comment: First I don't understand that I have to use 'edit' on my question. My question is still almost the same. And I did not find another 'edit'.. The popup on the green screen you posted I used in the beginning, so I already know about that (only not the style function which almost solves my problem). The problem remains that I get for 0.5 second before the login screen the color from the LightDM. I can make them simular/equal now with your help, but I wonder why I have to choose the same color in 2 tools: Desktop and LightDM. Hopefully I made it understandable.

Comment: Below your question are four links, the second one is Edit. LightDM is a program, that starts your desktop. So its like starting the graphical stack. That is the way in Linux. So if my answers helped you I would be happy if you could accept it (the sign left of my answer)

Comment: Maybe you missed my comments 1 hour ago?

Comment: Something indeed has changed now: Since I used Style=none in the background tool I am having 3 different background colors, not 2 anylonger. FIRST I am having 0.5 second green, THEN I am having a wave-like green pattern as a login screen and AT THE END I am having a black desktop background. So FIRST Light DM, THEN ?? and AT THE END desktop tool. Now I am wondering what part determines the color of the login screen? And why is it so difficult to set the background to one color?

Comment: When I unselect "use user wallpaper.." in your top picture, I get only 2 colors. Now the middle color is gone so FIRST I am having green, also in the login screen and THEN I am having black. Still I am wondering why is it so difficult to set the background to one color?

Comment: Sorry I'm out. I understand what you mean -but this description belongs into your question and not into a comment. The OP is supposed to describe his problem in his question, not in comments. Reason: Now that I understand your problem, I (or others qualified) could edit it in a way others would understand it also - without reading the whole comment thread.